# phonegap, iphone and the big bad idleTimerDisabled

Tags: iphone, cordova, idle-timer

reading a lot about how to prevent iphone goingto sleep while running my app I am very unhappy at the moment because nothing worked..

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058717/idletimerdisabled-not-working-since-iphone-3-0) I read about the idea to set up a timer for every 30 seconds to set the idleTimerDisabled to NO and then YES, but my objC isn't that good yet. could anybody tell me how (and where)?

thnx!

edit:
here is the code I tried:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [ super applicationDidFinishLaunching:application ];
    //application.idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    //application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;


}
```

edit2: after that I tried to start a loop with:

```
-(void)_timerLoop
{
    // add this function up the top.  it's what will happen when the
    // timer goes off:
    NSLog(@"Your timer went off!!!");
}


/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here.
 */
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [ super applicationDidFinishLaunching:application ];
    //application.idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    //application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(_timerLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}
```

edit3: you really can't change accidentially downvotes? would be a nice chnage request to the stackoverflow system!

Comment: why is my question downrated?

Comment: @JoeBlow: thanx! good to know. just edited the question as you asked me to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your question **about using a timer**:

Here is how you make a timer go off (just once) in 30 seconds from now:

```
-(void)_jump
{
// add this function up the top.  it's what will happen when the
// timer goes off:
NSLog(@"Your timer went off!!!");
}
...
// here's how to create the timer, which will go off in 30 seconds
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0
   target:self selector:@selector(_jump) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]
```

If you want **two different timers**, after say 30 and then 60 seconds, just make two in the same way. Let me know if you need more help with timers!

---

It couldn't be easier. Just add this line:

```
application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Inside your "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" routine.

You will find that routine inside your **app delegate** .m source code file.

Be sure to add it **BEFORE** the "return YES;" statement - a common mistake!  So, exactly like this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    // blah blah ...

    application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: there isn't a return YES in the AppDelegate.m. it is a (void) method:
`- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{ 
 [ super applicationDidFinishLaunching:application ];
    //application.idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    //application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

    
}`

Comment: @Joe Blow hey, thanx for your help! I am only using phonegap and in the appDelegate.m I added application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
to stop the ideTimer. but it did not work. if I did wrong so did the phonegap guys. ;-) so is this wrong?

Comment: @Joe Edited... Why is phonegap that crappy?

Comment: @Joe thanx for the try, but the timer doesn't work. (see edit)

Comment: hm, in '- (id) init' it is working. but when is '- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching' called ever?

Comment: this one looks good:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041368/phonegap-iphone-applicationdidfinishlaunching-not-invoking)

Comment: thnx! but unfort. there is no other way to use my sencha touch on mobiles. everything else costs some money...

Answer (score 1):

Just setting [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES; in

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions

works well for me. However, there is a caveat. I have noticed that every time I invoke camera utility from my phonegap app to take a snapshot, idleTimerDisable gets set to NO behind the scene. So right after i upload my image, I had call the following line of code again:

[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

Also, I would not be surprised if there are more places throughout the app idle timer gets reenabled.